# Receber parâmetros no $state

Tags: angularjs

No app.config tenho o seguinte $state:

```
.state('app.users.edit', {
            url: "/editar/:uid",              
            views: { 
                'content@' : {
                    templateUrl: 'view/users_edit.html',
                    controller: 'users_edit',
                    resolve: { auth : logged }
                }
            }
        });
```

Tenho uma lista com todos os utilizadores, o botão editar ficou configurado da seguinte forma:

```
<a href="#" ui-sref="app.users.edit">Editar ID {{user.id}}</a>
```

Não estou conseguindo passar o ID do utilizador para o $state.

Como faço para receber parâmetros no $state?

Answer (score 2):

Você tem de passar os parâmetros assim:

```
ui-sref="app.users.edit({ uid: 'parâmetro' })"
```

como se estivesse chamando uma função e passando para ela um mapa com o nome do parâmetro e o valor.